# Forwarding a port range to multiple machines

Tags: networking, port-forwarding

I have multiple PBXs sitting behind one WAN address. I use PJSIP and by default it's port is 5060, however, I have multiple clients that need to access their own PBX so here is my plan.

My plan is to have PJSIP listen on different ports for each PBX i.e. PBX-1 listens on port 5070 and PBX-2 listens on port 5071 etc, etc. But RTP traffic still needs to listen on ports 10000-20000.

I know I can't forward individual ports to multiple machines but what about a port range? Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything listening needs a unique port to listen on.  So no, you can't.  You can however, define multiple ports in that range to forward to multiple machines.  It would have to be a 1 to 1 correlation though.

Answer (score 2):

No. You can't forward a port range to multiple machines.